# Combine two prometheus queries and present the result as a boolean value

Tags: prometheus

Both of the following queries produce Boolean outputs.

Query1

```
state{token="59cdefc6f4e9ac94"}  1
```

Query2

```
state{token="c86fc1f35d479759"}  0
```

If Query2 exists, please combine the two prometheus queries according to the following logic.
If Query2 does not exist, please present the results of Query1 directly.

```
[Q1]&[Q2]
1  &  1  ->  1
1  &  0  ->  0
0  &  1  ->  0
0  &  0  ->  0

[Q1]
1  ->  1
0  ->  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent metric from being returned if other metric exists, using `unless`.
SO in this case we can use query

```
(
   vector(1)
   and on() (state{token="59cdefc6f4e9ac94"}==1)
   unless on() (state{token="c86fc1f35d479759"}==0)
) or vector(0)
```

This query will return one if any of time series in first selector is equal to 1, and second selector doesn't return any metrics with value 0. And zero otherwise.